# Wants to get last element's previous object. But returns null

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I made this list for working as a ring. I can get 2nd, 3rd element's previous objects here. But if I am going to get last element's  previous, it returns null. Can anyone correct this code.

### Ring

```
class Ring {

Customer ptr;

void add(Customer customer) {
    Customer temp = customer;
    if (ptr == null) {
        ptr = temp;
    } else {
        Customer x = ptr;
        Customer n = ptr;
        while (x.next != null) {
            x = x.next;
            n.next.prev = n;
            n = n.next;
        }
        x.next = temp;
    }

}

void printList() {
    Customer temp = ptr;
    System.out.println(temp.next.next.next.prev);
    while (temp != null) {
        //System.out.println(temp);
        temp = temp.next;
    }
}
}
```

### Main

```
class Main {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Ring list = new Ring();
    Customer c1 = new Customer("10011", "A");
    Customer c2 = new Customer("10012", "B");
    Customer c3 = new Customer("10013", "C");
    Customer c4 = new Customer("10014", "D");
    list.add(c1);
    list.add(c2);
    list.add(c3);
    list.add(c4);

    list.printList();

}
}
```

### Customer

```
class Customer {

String id;
String name;
Customer next;
Customer prev;

public Customer(String id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

public String toString() {
    return id + " : " + name;
}

public boolean equals(Object ob) {
    Customer c = (Customer) ob;
    return this.id.equals(c.id);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your add function you do, just after the while loop

```
x.next = temp;
```

which is great but u need to do also

```
x.next = temp;
temp.prev = x;
```

to the last item will point on it's previous item

and thus each item you add to the list is in the last of the list and will point to it's previous item only when the next item will be put into the list

```
void add(Customer customer)
{
    Customer temp = customer;

    if (ptr == null)
    {
        ptr = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        Customer x = ptr;
        Customer n = ptr;

        while (x.next != null)
        {
            x = x.next;
            n.next.prev = n;
            n = n.next;
        }

        x.next = temp;
        temp.prev = x;
        ptr.prev = temp;// ******** edited line ******
    }

}
```

Comment: If I gets 1st element's previous, it returns null here. I needs to get last element, if I gets previous of 1st element.

Comment: @RSST i've edited to code and added ptr.prev = temp; that should do it

Comment: If I want to add an element to a specified index how can I do it.

Comment: you add a counter to the add function, incrementing it by 1 in the while loop. when you get the needed index, you do break;

Answer (score 0):

In your method `add` inside your class `Ring`: your `else` clause would be simpler if you just go to the last element and then do the links, something like this:

```
void add(Customer customer) {
    Customer temp = customer;
    if (ptr == null) {
        ptr = temp;
    } else {
        Customer x = ptr;
        while (x.next != null) {
            x = x.next;
        }
        x.next = customer;
        customer.prev = x;
        customer.next = ptr;
        ptr.prev = customer;
    }

}
```

Comment: If I gets 1st element's previous, it returns null here. I needs to get last element, if I gets previous of 1st element.

Comment: @RSST try my modifications to your method `add()` (copy/paste the code above), it works for me